# simple text editor challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stack

While trying to solve [`Simple Text Editor`](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-text-editor) challenge from HackerRank, my solution passes only 3 of the 15 test cases. Since I don't have access to the test cases, am not able to figure out what exactly is wrong with my code.

My approach to solving the problem is as below -

1. Use a vector to hold the different states of the editor.
2. If we're appending to the `init` string (please refer to the code below), push it's new state at the back of vector. [OP_APPEND]
3. In case of deletion operation, push the new state of the `init` string at the back of vector as well. [OP_DELETE]
4. Since state of the `init` string is stored at the back of the vector, in case of multiple UNDO events, `init` string should be made to be in sync with the back of the vector. [OP_PRINT & OP_UNDO]

And below is my implementation -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define MAX_LEN     1000000
#define MAX_TIMES   100000

using namespace std;

/* Operations supported by editor */
enum EDITOR_OPS {
    OP_APPEND = 1,
    OP_DELETE,
    OP_PRINT,
    OP_UNDO
};

/*
 * @brief   Driver function
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned times;             /* Total number of operations */
    unsigned option;            /* EDITOR_OPS operations */
    string init = "";           /* Initial string */
    string mystr;               /* Temp string */
    unsigned num;               /* Number used in OP_DELETE & OP_PRINT comms */

    vector<string> myvect;      /* To hold various states of the editor */
    unsigned curr_len = 0;      /* Sum of lengths of all characters entered */

    cin >> times;
    if (times >= 1 && times <= MAX_TIMES) {
        for (auto i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            cin >> option;
            if (option >= 1 && option <= 4) {
                if (option == OP_APPEND) {
                    cin >> mystr;
                    curr_len += mystr.length();
                    if (curr_len <= MAX_LEN) {
                        init.append(mystr);
                        myvect.push_back(init);
                    }
                }
                else if (option == OP_DELETE) {
                    cin >> num;
                    if (num >=1 && num <= init.length()) {
                        init.erase(init.length() - num);
                        myvect.push_back(init);
                    }
                }
                else if (option == OP_PRINT) {
                    cin >> num;
                    if (!myvect.empty())
                        init = myvect.back();
                    if (num >= 1 && num <= init.length())
                        cout << init.at(num - 1) << "\n";
                }
                else if (option == OP_UNDO) {
                    if (!myvect.empty())
                        myvect.pop_back();
                }
                else {
                    cout << "We should NOT get in here\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please help me figure out the bug(s) in my code and/or the corner cases I am missing?

Comment: `3. print(k) - print the *kth* character of S`

Comment: You should remove `if (option >= 1 && option <= 4)` so that you can see "We should NOT get in here" if something is wrong.

Comment: "Since I don't have access to the test cases, am not able to figure out what exactly is wrong with my code." If your code's not working, writing your own test cases is an excellent place to begin debugging -- and this is how it is in real-world programming too. Staring at the code is not the only two ways to debug...

Comment: Unknown test cases means your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens in your code if you undo and then append.

- append expects `init` to contain the current value of the string.
- Undo just removes the last operation and leaves `init` as it is, meaning it doesn't match the current state.

You need to change one of the above behaviours.

I suspect when you were testing you always did a print after one or more undo operations.